# Docker torchserve NS_ERROR_NET_RESET

Tags: docker

I followed instructions [here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/AnimatedDrawings/#animating-your-own-drawing) in order to run a docker container running a torchserve instance.

The image build went fine :

```
docker build -t docker_torchserve .
```

and the running container as well.

```
docker run -d --name docker_torchserve -p 8080:8080 -p 8081:8081 docker_torchserve
```

Container logs show a torchserve running correctly.

I get an NS_ERROR_NET_RESET error when trying curl http://localhost:8080/ping.

What can cause this request to fail ?

From what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60984025/1317323) it could come from a wrong binding on the container but the config.properties file seems ok :

```
inference_address=http://0.0.0.0:8080
management_address=http://0.0.0.0:8081
metrics_address=http://0.0.0.0:8082
model_store=/home/torchserve/model-store
load_models=all
```

I use docker desktop on Windows 11 pro.